# How access element at an index of generator in python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am new to python & facing issue while accessing second element of iterateable returned by function from lib pyyaml, yaml.load_all, below is code:

```
import os
import yaml
file = "abc.yaml"
stream = open(file)
docs = yaml.load_all(stream)
print docs[1]
```

output I am getting is

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

yaml is python lib for handling [yaml](http://www.yaml.org/) format, 
yaml.load_all is explained [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML)

Comment: `docs` in this case is actually `None`, not an iterable. Can you please provide a full code example? What is `yaml` in this case? Where did it come from?

Comment: As @Ffisegydd said, it's `None` in this case. If it was iterable, you could use `next` function to get next element from iterable.

Comment: but then i can do a for on it eg:
   `for doc in docs:
      print doc`

Comment: Again, can you please provide a fully working example?

Comment: this is completed code I have written so far

Comment: @Shanky : you _can not_ "do a for" (=> iterate) on `None` - it very obviously raises a `TypeError` with 'NoneType' object is not iterable'. And your example is not "fully working" without the exact content of "abc.yaml".

Answer (score 0):

If you only need that one document, then this should do:

```
docs = yaml.load_all(...)
next(docs)  # skip docs[0]
mydoc = next(docs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you mention (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`) does not come from `docs` being a generator but from `docs` being `None`.

But anyway, to answer your question: you cannot "access element at an index in a generator", because generator are not subscriptable - the whole point of generators is to generate values on the fly. If you really need a subscriptable sequence, the simplest way is to build a `list` from your generator, ie:

```
docs = list(yaml.load_all(stream))
```

Now **beware** that you'd rather not do this unless you know for sure that 1. your generator  is not infinite (generators *can* be infinite and some are) and 2. the list will fit in memory.

NB : I use the word "generator" here but it applies to iterators in general.